# Как получить значение из объекта PHP?

Tags: php, битрикс

Получаю следующий объект:

```
    Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Result Object
    (
        [instance:protected] => Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task Object
            (
                [id:protected] => 443904
                [userId:protected] => 0
                [transitionState:protected] => Bitrix\Tasks\Item\State Object
                    (
                        [isInside:protected] =>
                        [result:protected] => Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Result Object
                            (
                                [instance:protected] =>
                                [errors:protected] => Bitrix\Tasks\Util\Error\Collection Object
                                    (
                                        [fatalCount:protected] => 0
                                        [values:protected] => Array
                                            (
                                            )

                                    )

                                [data:protected] =>
                            )

                        [time:protected] => 0
                        [mode:protected] => 1
                        [parameters:protected] =>
                        [values:protected] => Array
                            (
                            )

                    ) 
...
```

Как мне из него получить значение **443904**?

Comment: Ента же битрикс)) 
`$this->getId();`

пробовали так?))

Comment: Они оборачивают защищенные методы в публичные геттеры

Comment: В общем надо в bxapi.ru ковыряться или в исходниках, благо они под рукой

Comment: Как минимум судя по доке `Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Result::getInstance` существует. Но кого интересует дока если можно корежить рефлексию и наследовать непонятно зачем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы получить информацию о создании задачи достаточно вызвать метод `getData` после создания задачи.

Пример:

```
$task = new \Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task(0, 1);
$task->save();
$taskResult = $task->getData();
```

Comment: Неверный способ. Вы не получите ID новой задачи. Пример: Array
(
    [ID] => 
    [TITLE] => Task title
    [DESCRIPTION] => Task description
    [DESCRIPTION_IN_BBCODE] => Y
    [PRIORITY] => 2

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант, если битрикс таки не оборачивают:

```
class CustomTask extends Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task
{
    public function getTaskId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

И уже вызывать CustomTask

Answer (score 1):

В общем у меня получилось добраться к id через защищённые свойства, но думаю есть более простой способ, кто знает прошу написать.
Вот мой вариант:

```
class A{
    protected $b;

    public function __construct(B $b){
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class B{
    protected $id = 43243;
}


$a = new A(new B);

$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('A');
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('b');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

$bClass = $reflectionProperty->getValue($a);
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($bClass);
$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('id');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);

print_r($reflectionProperty->getValue($bClass));
```

Сначала я сделал доступным свойство класса `A` и затем уже взялся за `id` 
Структура такая же как и у вас, вам стоит только заменить переменные

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть все методы объекта, то увидим, что нет метода для получения id. Поэтому единственный вариант, кроме расширения класса Битрикс, использовать зеркальный класс:

```
function accessProtected($obj, $prop) {
  $reflection = new \ReflectionClass($obj);
  $property = $reflection->getProperty($prop);
  $property->setAccessible(true);
  return $property->getValue($obj);
}
```

Еще один недостаток - вложенность свойств, поэтому эту функцию придется вызвать дважды:

```
$inst = self::accessProtected($result, 'instance');
$id = self::accessProtected($inst, 'id');
```

Но использовать такой метод в Production можно только после профайлинга. А если нужно более изящное решения, то нужно искать реализацию подобных задач в исходных кодах самого Битрикс:

```
bash: grep -r 'Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Task' /path/to/bitrix/
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо никаких доп классов для заворачивания результата. Как правильно написали выше - можно инициализировать создание объекта класса типа `Bitrix\Tasks\Item\Result`

```
$taskId = $result->getInstance()->getId();
```

Answer (score -2):

Пришлось решить вопрос через init.php, там отследить событие создания задачи. Как раз и возвращается id.

Comment: Это неправильный подход. Если только вам не нужно отлавливать событие создания абсолютно всех задач. Зачем создавать лишнюю нагрузку на портал и замедлять создание задач?